# Default line spacing in Powerpoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint, vba, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I want to set the default line spacing in Powerpoint 2007 to 1.1 rather than 0.8 which Microsoft has set as default. Is there any way to do this?

Alternatively, I could also manage if I could create a macro that does this. But MS have also removed the Macro Recorder from PP2007. Can somebody help with the VBA code??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you make a macro, you can use this code:

```
Sub SetLineSpacing()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
  For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    *If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then*
       With shp.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
          .LineRuleWithin = msoTrue
          .SpaceWithin = 1.1
       End With
     *End If*
   Next
 Next
End Sub
```

But there is one flaw. When you have some text with line spacing 3 (for example) but there is no space to have this kind of line spacing, powerpoint will automatically reduce it, ie. to 2.8. When you run this macro then, the line spacing will become 1.2 or 1.3 or something like that. Only when you run the macro a second time, it will repair this problem. I could not figure out where this problem was coming from though, since debugging the code made it work flawless from first run.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the effort. I tried your solution but am getting an error - that the specified value is out of range. Please see these screenshots for more details of the error: http://goo.gl/lLCK4 and  and http://goo.gl/ssVFD

Comment: @vinayak I updated the code with an extra check if the shape contains some text. This error happens mostly on tables or placeholder shapes with no text in them. (the * are to show the edited lines of code, remove before use)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but people should know that you don't need code for this! I'm using 2013, but I believe this worked the same way in 2007. Just go to View / Slide Master, click on the master slide (the top one), then click in the main text placeholder. Ctrl-a to select all, then right-click, choose Paragraph and change the Line Spacing to Multiple 1.1. Voila, it will ripple through to every layout and every slide.

If you've already overridden the default on any slides, then go to each of those slides and, on the Home tab in the Slides section, choose Reset. (Note this will reset all changes you've made to the entire slide.)